# making zip process more optimized one

Tags: java, performance, zip

I have developed a method to zip a file that will take file path and filename as a parameter and will zip a file as shown below could you please advise how can I modify this method to be more efficient and more fast as I am a big fan of optimization..

```
public File generateZipForAFile(String folderPath, String reportFileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File inputFile = new File(folderPath + reportFileName);
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

    File outputZipFile = new File(folderPath, reportFileName + ".zip");
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputZipFile));
    // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(reportFileName ));

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    out.closeEntry();
    out.close();
    in.close();
    return outputZipFile;
}
```

Comment: Change your byte buffer to a size of `8192`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis YEAH but please advise the benefit for that what will be the impact in performance if i make it size of 8192

Comment: If you read more each time, you will make less IO OS calls to the disk.

Comment: I've added 2 tags for you. Tags make it easier for others to find or spot your question, in particular people who are familiar with the subject and have favoured a certain tag.

Comment: look at changing buf to a ByteBuffer and use ByteBuffer.allocateDirect, it will likely be faster as it maps the file.

Comment: @dru could you please post the code that will help to grasp more

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do in your code. Furthermore, most of the time is spent while actually doing the zip.

So even if you reduce the time spent in your part to 0 the overall gain will be very small.